# Android Studio Java display text file contents in new lines

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile, append, text-files

Im creating a weight tracking app where the user inputs their weight clicks a save button and then the weight is saved. There is also a load button that loads all the previous inputs. The problem I'am having is that once load is clicked it does load up the weights on the screen but it does it all in one line other than a separate line for each.

I have checked the text file and all the weights are stored in a line each so there's no problem in the function that stores the inputs.

Here is the code for the `weight tracker

```
package com.example.workouttracker;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class WeightTracking extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "WeightTracking.txt";


    EditText mEditText;
    EditText mEditText2;
    private Button button_back_home;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weight_tracking);

        mEditText = findViewById(R.id.weight);
        mEditText2 = findViewById(R.id.weight2);

        button_back_home=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_back_home);
        button_back_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                homePage();
            }
            private void homePage(){
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
            }
        });

    }
    public void save(View v) {
        String text = mEditText.getText().toString();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_APPEND);
            fos.write((text + "kg's\n").getBytes());


            mEditText.getText().clear();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to " + getFilesDir() + "/" + FILE_NAME,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void load(View v) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String text;
            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(text);
                sb.append('\n');
            }
            mEditText2.setText(sb.toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Someone know's how to get it to load each weight line by line?
Thanks

`

Comment: I'm no Android dev so I can't say for sure what Android uses to define a line break but `\n` might not be the right thing. If it was HTML you'd have to use `<br/>` and maybe that's what Android wants as well. If not, I'd refer you to the documentation. Also note that from using Google here I get the impression that EditText would also need to be set up for multiline text so that might be missing too.

Answer (score 0):

can you please check your xml file, if you have added property  `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` on the edittext

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code like this:

```
String sb = "";
String text;
while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb = sb + text + "\n";
}
```